# Restart Elasticservice once a day using cronjob

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

In server, I can just do

```
sudo /etc/init.d/elasticsearch restart
```

for restarting the Elasticsearch service, now I'm having a problem with the elastic node where it says

> no alive nodes found

So I have to restart it by doing so the command above. Is there a way I could schedule the Elasticsearch service restart once a day? I came across with cron jobs but seems not to be working.

Comment: Why do you need to restart your Elasticsearch service on daily basis?

Comment: @SandeepKanabar I'm still figuring out why I'm running out of nodes

Comment: Can you please describe in little more detail what you mean by running out of nodes? As in the node leaves the Elasticsearch cluster and you’ve to restart it to make it again join the cluster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`crontab` is just what you need. If your service restarts with `sudo`, you should set cron jobs for root, to do this run `sudo crontab -e` and add `@daily /etc/init.d/elasticsearch restart`